# Change property of an item inside a GridView?

Tags: xaml, gridview, data-binding, uwp, c++-cx

I have a GridView, with this item template (XAML):

```
<DataTemplate x:DataType="local:MyClass">
      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind MyString}"/>
      <Button Command="{x:Bind command}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Here's `MyClass` (C++/CX)

```
public ref class MyClass sealed
{
 public:
     MyClass();
     property Platform::String^ MyString
     {
          String^ get()
            {
               return mystring;
            }
     }
     property ICommand^ command = ref new DelegateCommand(ref new ExecuteDelegate(this, &implementcommand), nullptr);
     private:
         String^ mystring;
         void implementcommand(Platform::Object^ param);
}
```

The `DelegateCommand` function is pulled from this sample without modifications: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Command-binding-inside-3cef5eea
Right now, if I click any of the buttons in the gridview, it will call `implementcommand`. However, I want to have `implementcommand` do something with the TextBlock control, for example changing the content of the text. From any function inside the `mainpage` class, and if it wasn't inside the gridview, it would be as simple as `textBlock->Text = ref new String("hello");` However, since the control is inside the gridview, and the implementcommand function is in `MyClass`, not `MainPage`, I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the TextBlock in your DataTemplate you bind the Text to a MyString property which (judging by the bindings I see) exists in the same class as the command.

What you need to do is

1. In your implementcommand change the value of MyString
2. Call
   Bindings.Update()

There is also another way (the classic way before x:Bind was available)

1. Change the binding mode in the TextBlock to OneWay
2. In your class implement INotifyPropertyChanged
3. In your implementcommand change the value of MyString and raise INotifyPropertyChanged event.

Comment: Thanks for answering. How would I call Bindings.Update() from inside `MyClass` though? `Bindings` is in `MainPage`, so I can't access it...

Comment: Ok, I figured out a solution to my previous comment. I put `friend ref class MyClass` in the `MainPage` class, then in the constructor of `MyClass`, I put `MyClass(MainPage x)`. I then called the constructor with `MyClass(this)` Then I could access members of `MainPage` by doing `x->Bindings->Update()`. However, `Bindings->Update()` only updates the controls outside of the gridview for me. Anything inside the GridView was not updated, and if I did not have any bound controls outside the gridview, the application threw an exception with a nullptr. Any ideas?

Comment: @justanotherxl Check out [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5e0a094f-00b9-4de8-aca0-4a27b333b54d/xbind-only-working-after-two-updates-classic-bind-works-fine?forum=wpdevelop) to see a better way to call Bindings.Update. It's better for your Page to have a dependency on MyClass than the other way round. 

I can't think of a reason why Bindings.Update updates everything else outside the GridView. Have you changed the GridView's DataContext?